# Finding value in XML based on tag not absolute position

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

EDIT: Ultimately, I am looking to have the output under the static position and find element should be the same. Currently I am able to get the value using the static position in the array, however, when searching based on a tag, I get no results.

I'm sort of new to working with Python and XML and am hitting a brick wall and hoping that someone may be able to offer some insight. I have been tasked with working with an API into one of our applications to inject some custom fields based on data received via XML from another application. Part of that involves using said API to find an internal identifier based on a common identifier and the value that I need to continue the process is sent back through the API as XML data. I am able to retrieve the value if I specify the absolute location of the XML tag/value, but when I try to search by the name of the tag, I come back with garbage. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried using etree.find, etree.findall, etree.findtext and none of them seem to work. Below is an example (with some redactions to protect the innocent) of what I've been trying to do as well as a sample of the XML data that the API returns when I search.

Python script for API request:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


    PSExpData = s.get(URLpostvars, verify=False)

PSOrderXML = ET.fromstring(PSExpData.text)
PSOrderID = PSOrderXML[0][0].text

OrderIDElement = PSOrderXML.findtext("OrderID", namespaces="http://vendor.com/commissure/webservices/explorer/2010/06")
print (PSExpData.text)
print (f"Order ID from static position: {PSOrderID}")
print (f"Order ID from find element: {OrderIDElement}")
```

Example of returned XML data

```
<ArrayOfOrderData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://vendor.com/commissure/webservices/explorer/2010/06">
    <OrderData>
        <OrderID>15397</OrderID>
        <ReportID>0</ReportID>
        <Accession>T0000000</Accession>
        <Site>SITE</Site>
        <OrderDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</OrderDate>
        <Procedures>IMG3022</Procedures>
        <Status>Scheduled</Status>
        <Patient>LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME</Patient>
    </OrderData>
</ArrayOfOrderData>
```

What python says when I try to do the above... when I comment out line 30 as well as the print line, it works fine with the static position:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "findorder.py", line 30, in <module>
    OrderIDElement = PSOrderXML.findtext("OrderID", namespaces="http://vendor.com/commissure/webservices/explorer/2010/06")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 320, in findtext
    elem = next(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 268, in iterfind
    else tuple(sorted(namespaces.items())))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I've gone back and forth with this several times and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm not sure if this might have anything to do with the fact that I'm getting the XML back as an HTTP response and need to handle things differently but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user5173426 I have included more information about the desired output. I am trying to manage to parse out the OrderID based on the name of the tag and not based on the absolute position within the array. PSOrderID and OrderIDElement should be identical.

Comment: Replace with `OrderIDElement = PSOrderXML.findtext(".//ns:OrderID", namespaces={'ns':"http://vendor..."})`. The `dict` value `'ns'` replaces `ns:` in `xpath`. Read about [xpath-support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

Comment: @stovfl That worked perfectly, if you want to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as solved. Thank you very much! I haven't seen any references to namespaces like that, they all showed the way that I called it in my script. Thanks again!